# Linker complains of multiple definition of function in C code, when there is only one

Tags: c, linker, mingw

I'm using Qt Creator running with the mingw C++ compiler to compile some C sources I obtained from an institution known as the NBIS.
I'm trying to extract just the code that will allow me to decode images encoded in the WSQ image format.

Unfortunately I'm getting messages that I have "multiple definitions" of certain functions
which is contradicted by a grep search, as well as complaints of undefined functions which are indeed defined in a single C file in each case.
I looked at the include files and these functions do have the word extern before them in the declarations.
As for the error messages of "multiple definitions" the linker says "first defined here" and only gives one object file in each case.

All C files have a C extension.

I should add that I'm getting strange messages when I look at the compiler outout like this:
Makefile.Debug:427: warning: overriding recipe for target 'debug/huff.o' 
(it is true that I have two files called huff.c,but in different directories)

Comment: It would help if you can whittle down your program to something small enough to post here, including the compiler commands.

Comment: That very difficult. There are dozens of files!

Comment: That's why I said whittle it down.  You should be able to keep removing bits until you have something you can post.

Comment: To me this sounds like the _definition_ of an `extern` function is somehow being #included in two different translation units, while at other times not being included at all. Does this source code _define_ non-`static` functions in headers? Are you using `#include`-guard macros with every header, and are the `#include`-guards _actually_ distinct between one another? I've been bitten more than once by forgetting to change the include-guard macro identifers when copying headers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance including these .h in .cpp files (in addition to C files)? In which case you need to surround them by an `extern "C"` statement:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "CHeader.h"
}
```

Comment: Qt creates a single main.cpp file, but so far the only thing I have added to it is **int debug=0**;

Answer (score 0):

I was using "shadow-build" which creates a directory outside of the source file hierarchy
into which Qt places the makefile it generates from the project file, puts the object files
and so forth. 
I deleted that directory and reran the Qt Build operation.
The problem went away.
Looks like it's a Qt bug.